# Custom resolution not working creating a Virtual Device

Tags: android, android-studio

I've created a custom hardware profile with the resolution of 800x600px (ldpi). But the problem is when I run the app in the device it looks like a ultra high density app.

This is how the app looks in the Nexus 10 profile:

[image]

This looks correct. But when I run the device with a lower resolution it looks like a much higher resolution for some reason:

[image]

Those are the two options I have:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. never fixed this issue, it looks like a bug. But I noticed is that I don't have this problem If I use a 7 inch screen.

800x600px (ldpi) with 7'' screen works fine. 800x600px (ldpi) with a 10'' screen have this issue.